# Can I compile a Visual C++ project on Linux using xbuild?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, mono, xbuild

I have an existing project that I compile on both Windows using Visual C++ 2008, and Debian Linux. This project uses a standard Visual C++ `.vcproj` file, and some `.cpp` and `.h` files. It does not rely on any Windows specific stuff. Just plain C++.

It compiles and run well on Linux, using a *home made tool* that reads the `.vcproj` file to generate a `Makefile` which is used with `make` to compile and link all files using `g++`.

The trouble is that with Visual C++ 2010 (and 2012), the format of the project files have changed. Even the name has been changed from `.vcproj` to `.vcxproj`. My *home made tool* cannot read this new project file to generate the `Makefile`.

Instead of upgrading the *home made tool* to support new project files, I was wondering if `xbuild` would be able to compile my Linux executable?

I tried first to compile my own (VC++2008) project, but `xbuild` complains that my project `is a VS2003 project, which is not supported by xbuild.` However when googling on this matter, I find that `xbuild` is supposed to support VS2005 project files. There are also some references to `mdtool` to support these old project files, but I seems to be integrated into `xbuild` now.

Furthermore, I tried to compile a Visual C++ 2010 example (HuoChess) got from the MSDN site. The result is

```
/Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props: Project file could not be imported, it was being
imported by [...] /HuoChessConsole/HuoChessConsole.vcxproj: Imported project:
"//Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" does not exist.`
```

Now, this looks like the project file wants some *Microsoft* definitions of *rules* for the `Cpp` compiler. Should I fake these definitions to use `gcc` instead? How can I do this?

Is what I want to do ever possible with `xbuild`?

Comment: The best option is to create brand new mono project with the files used in vs2010 project and edit the configuration accordingly. Trying to match msbuild and other msstuff to anythig reasonable is wasting of time.

Comment: Applying the only rule of sticking with relative paths (to avoid drive letter), a tool can easily change all ` \ ` to ` / ` . It can even get environment variables and change `$(ProjectDir)` et al. macros. That's at least what I've been doing very successfully for more than 8 years.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project [GCCBuild](https://github.com/roozbehid/GCCBuild) which you can use to build vcxproj projects in Linux. It simply uses same vcxproj but uses GCC to compile and build. There are multiple examples there too.

PS. I am the author of that project.